# Dismissing ProgressDialog after WebPage finishes loading

Tags: android, url, webview, progressdialog

Iam loading a url into a `WebView`. This is a login page. When the user is authenticated he is shown a page. I stop the loading at this point and start another activity.

When the login button is hit, the user is redirected to first url. I start a progress dialog at this point. After he reaches the authenticated page I want to stop the progress dialog and directly want to show the new activity. I dont want the user to see the authenticated page.

Right now the Progress dialog stops at the authenticated page. The user sees it and then he is shown the next activity

Any help on how this can be achieved?

Here is my code:-

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            myWebView.loadUrl(url);

            final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Details1.this, "Loading..", "Please wait!");

            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {



                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    url= view.getUrl();
                    redirected= Uri.decode(url);

                        if(redirected!=null &&redirected.contains("Visited"))
                        {
                            myprogressDialog= new Utility.ProgressDialogFragment().newInstance();
                            myprogressDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Wait");
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    url= view.getUrl();
                    redirected= Uri.decode(url);

                        if(progressBar!=null && progressBar.isShowing())
                        {
                            progressBar.dismiss();
                        }






                 if(redirected!=null && redirected.startsWith(endpointHost+"/Authorize/index/"+device))//&& myprogressDialog!=null && myprogressDialog.isVisible())
                    {



                             myWebView.stopLoading();

                        myprogressDialog.dismiss();


                        String authorizationContentString =  myurl;
                        authorizationContentString =authorizationContentString.replace("|", "%7C");


                        new AuthenticateDevice(Details1.this,  Url).execute(authorizationContentString);




                    }



                }


                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    view.loadUrl(url);


                    return true;

                }


            });

        }
        private static class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
        {
             public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance()
                {
                    return new ProgressDialogFragment();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_progress, container, false);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: What actually is your need??I dint get you..

Comment: @Lal I want to stop the progress dialog after the authenticated page is shown. This is a dialog fragment. I dont want the authenticated page to be displayed and directly switch to next activity. So that after login the user is directly shown the next activity

Comment: Start your new activity when the onPageStarted() started with the specific url and let the webview to onPageFinished() and stop the progDialog there and finish the webview activity. so that the web view will be under the new activity in stack and web view will be hided from the user.

Comment: @Sripathi can you elaborate a bit with my code?

Comment: @user3627247 Please look at my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            myWebView.loadUrl(url);

            final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Details1.this, "Loading..", "Please wait!");

            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {


                boolean toStopLoading = false;
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    url= view.getUrl();
                    redirected= Uri.decode(url);

                        if(redirected!=null &&redirected.contains("Visited"))
                        {
                            myprogressDialog= new Utility.ProgressDialogFragment().newInstance();
                            myprogressDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Wait");
                            toStopLoading = true;
                           // start your new activity here.
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    url= view.getUrl();
                    redirected= Uri.decode(url);

                        if(progressBar!=null && progressBar.isShowing())
                        {
                            progressBar.dismiss();
                        }

                        if(toStopLoading){
                      // finish your web view activity here.
                        }



                 if(redirected!=null && redirected.startsWith(endpointHost+"/Authorize/index/"+device))//&& myprogressDialog!=null && myprogressDialog.isVisible())
                    {



                             myWebView.stopLoading();

                        myprogressDialog.dismiss();


                        String authorizationContentString =  myurl;
                        authorizationContentString =authorizationContentString.replace("|", "%7C");


                        new AuthenticateDevice(Details1.this,  Url).execute(authorizationContentString);


                    }



                }


                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    view.loadUrl(url);


                    return true;

                }


            });

        }
        private static class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
        {
             public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance()
                {
                    return new ProgressDialogFragment();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_progress, container, false);
                }
        }
}
```

Try this..

Comment: AuthenticateDevice is my AsyncTask where Iam starting my new Activity

Comment: You mentioned that your are starting new activity when redirected to first url. I made some changes(set a boolean toStopLoading) please go through that. And explain me clearly what you need and poso the AsyncTask to verify.